# How does OkHttp interceptor is working in Retrofit Android?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

One thing I don't undefstand, if you see the below code:

```
 val request = chain.request()
    val response = chain.proceed(request)
    val tag = getRequestTag(request)

    LogUtils.d("Hello req: " + request)
    LogUtils.d("Hello code: " + response.code)
```

Here in this application interceptor, request is printing properly and also getting response code as 200. But let's say now I modified the request

```
    request.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader(AppConstants.INetworkValues.HEADER_PRAGMA).build()


    LogUtils.d("Hello req1: " + request)
    LogUtils.d("Hello code1: " + response.code)
```

So, again I'm getting code as 200. it means if I use interceptor and do any modification, then API is hitting twice to server, but this is wrong, it should be called once only with modification

Entire code:

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val request = chain.request()
    val response = chain.proceed(request)
    val tag = getRequestTag(request)

    LogUtils.d("Hello req: " + request)
    LogUtils.d("Hello code: " + response.code)

    request.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader(AppConstants.INetworkValues.HEADER_PRAGMA).build()


    LogUtils.d("Hello req1: " + request)
    LogUtils.d("Hello code1: " + response.code)
    return chain.proceed(request)
}
```

PS: I know at the end, I'll get callback only once, but internally it called twice, it means unnecessary operation!

EDIT:

```kotlin
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val request: Request = chain.request() 
    val response = chain.proceed(request) 
    return response.newBuilder().code(code).build() 
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to call chain.process() twice. If you want the interceptor to perform the network call, your last return to should be: return response (and not return chain.proceed(request).

Comment: @gioravered let's say I want to modify the response code in that case? override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        return response.newBuilder().code(code).build()
    }

Comment: Looks ok but I didn't test your code. proceed() executes the request. This means that everything after (other interceptors as well) will execute after the request was sent to the internet.

Comment: @gioravered Simple question: My API is giving 200, but I want to modify and send my app to 400. In that internal call must happen twice, let me know if you think it will call only once

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The code you added in the comments is not calling the API twice. You only call chain.proceed() once.

Comment: @gioravered Please check the edited code

Comment: What should I check? Is it working for you?

Comment: @gioravered Yes, that is working, but my question is in that edited code, internal request to server will be made twice correct?

Comment: Sorry for not answering, I was away. The proceed() call by itself is not executing the network call. It simply calls the next interceptor (Chain Of Responsibilities pattern) according to the order the interceptors were added. The After the last interceptor executes, the network call is performed. You should not call proceed() twice. Explain what you are trying to achieve and it will be easier to help.